# Canon 18 - 55 IS STM lens noisey

Tags: canon, zoom

I've recently brought a brand new canon lens from a website and when I record videos and use the zoom, you can really hear it during playback?  Is this normal? 
Here's a link to a video I've recorded: https://twitter.com/elllisn/status/850318225531383808

Please help as I don't know if I should send the lens back or not? Or is it because the lens is new so it's still slightly stiff?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For any serious video filming on a multi-function camera, use an external mic.  Some motors and mechanisms are very noisy, some are only slightly noisy.  You should be aiming for NO noise.

Also turn off any Auto Volume Control option.  It is designed to turn down over-loud sounds.  Therefore it has the effect of turning up quiet ones.  Exactly what you DON'T want.

Answer (score 0):

STM has nothing to do with the zoom, it has to do with the focus which seems to be fairly quiet with your lens. When you zoom the air displaced by the changing volume of the lens has to go somewhere. When you zoom that fast it is being forced through the dust filter fast enough to create sound.

Answer (score 0):

The noise you hear is simply the plastic on plastic sliding of the zoom mechanism.  It is completely normal. There is nothing you can do really do about it other than zooming more slowly, or use an external microphone.